# Relationship between two tables one with 2 foreign keys in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, relationship, flask-sqlalchemy

I've two tables representing users and messages as follows:

```
class Users (db.Model):
    UserId = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    UserName = db.Column(db.String(25),nullable=False, unique=True)
    Email = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False,unique=True)

class Messages (db.Model):
    MessageId = db.Column(db.INTEGER,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    SenderId = db.Column(db.INTEGER,db.ForeignKey('Users.UserId'),nullable=False)
    ReceiverId = db.Column(db.INTEGER,db.ForeignKey('Users.UserId'),nullable=False)
    Message = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
```

I'd like to know that If I want to write the following in Users class:

> db.relationship ('Messages', backref='MessageSender', lazy='dynamic' # this return message sender.
>
> db.relationship ('Messages', backref='MessageReceiver', lazy='dynamic' #this returns message receiver.

How should I specify that ? so that I can backref both foreign keys ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work:

```
class Messages(db.Model):
    MessageId = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    SenderId = db.Column(db.INTEGER, db.ForeignKey('users.UserId'), nullable=False)
    ReceiverId = db.Column(db.INTEGER, db.ForeignKey('users.UserId'), nullable=False)
    Message = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    # define relationships
    sender = db.relationship(Users, foreign_keys=[SenderId], backref='sent')
    receiver = db.relationship(Users, foreign_keys=[ReceiverId], backref='received')
```

Usage example:

```
u0 = Users(UserName='Lila')
u1 = Users(
    UserName='John',
    sent=[Messages(Message='hi', receiver=u0)]
)
```